# How to programatically create button in android allowing to toggle dns check ?

Tags: java, android-widget, android

I need to create a button in my app, that allows the user to select wether the dns check should be enabled or disabled (same as *#*#4636#*#* -> toggle DNS Check ( http://www.honeytechblog.com/toggle-dns-samsung-galaxys/ )).

Is this possible ?

The reason is that on Android devices that are not a phone (tablets), there is no option to enter this "INFO"-menu .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 of your question:

```
<!-- language: java -->
Button buttonView = new Button(this);
buttonView.setText("Button " + i);
layout.addView(buttonView, p);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, allthough it was stupid of me to ask the question ;-) I am familiar with how to add the button, but the real question is how to have that button to access the "toggle DNS"-setting. Thanks anyway.